# golang regexp.MatchString handle url match

Tags: regex, go

I wanna check if a url string match keyword, for example, keyword is `google.com`, if url string is `google.com` or `https://google.com`, then return `true`, if url is `google.com/search` or something like that, return `true`, if url is `google.com.id`, then return `false` as it's a different url, I tried one as below but it doesn't work, how to write regular expression? thank u

```
regexp.MatchString(`^(?:https?://)?([-a-z0-9]+)(?:\.`+keyword+`)*$`, urlstr)
```

btw, as far as I understood, regular expression will cause some performance issue, anyone can provide other solutions to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```golang
regexp.MatchString(`^(?:https?://)?(?:[^/.\s]+\.)*` + regexp.QuoteMeta(keyword) + `(?:/[^/\s]+)*/?$`)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ohxUcG/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:[^/\s]+\.)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `[^/.\s]+` - one or more chars other than `/`, `.` and whitespace
  - `\.` - a dot
- `google\.com` - an escaped `keyword`
- `(?:/[^/\s]+)*` -  zero or more repetitions of a `/` and then one or more chars other than `/` and whitespace chars
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string

Note you need to use [`regexp.QuoteMeta`](https://godoc.org/regexp#QuoteMeta) to escape any special chars in the `keyword`, like a `.` that matches any char but line break chars by default.

Comment: thank u, seems works, if there will be some performance issue on regular expression? any other solutions to handle it?

Comment: @Frank I think this regex is efficient enough not to cause any performance problems. Note I assumed there will be no spaces in the URL. If you need to support whitespace, remove all `\s`s.

Comment: understood, thank u, let me do benchmark for it

Comment: hi got a bug, if keyword is `https://google.com` which contains `https`, but urlstr is `google.com` which not contains `https`, result will be false, but expected should be true. how to change above expression?

Comment: @Frank This is a problem with your data/task definition. If you need to handle URLs with protocol or without in keywords, make sure you only check the parts without protocol, simply remove it with `strings.Replace(strings.Replace(urlstr, "https://", "", 1), "http://", "", 1)` before checking.